# Access list by sublist names

Tags: r, list

I have a list of lists (output of a foreach loop) such that each list gets the same fields. Now I'd like to invert this list avoiding a for loop.

MWE:

```
out_list <- list(list(a = matrix(1:3), b = 2, c = '3'),
             list(a = matrix(11:13), b= 22, c = '33'))
```

I'd like to get:

```
new_list$a = list(matrix(1:3), matrix(11:13))
new_list$b = list(2, 22)
new_list$c = list('3', '33')
```

I've tried using `unlist` to but it didn't produce the expected result.

thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We flatten the 'out_list' to create 'lst', `split` it by the `names` of 'lst' and if needed the change the names to NULL within the `list`.

```
 lst <- do.call("c", out_list)
 lst1 <- split(lst, names(lst))
 lst2 <- lapply(lst1, setNames, NULL)
 identical(lst2, new_list)
 #[1] TRUE
```

Comment: `do.call("c", out_list)`was brilliant, thanks ! `lst2`could be `lst2 <- lapply(lst1, unname)`.